# cant alert id button by clicking id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

***View***

```
<?php $no=1; foreach($result as $r){?>
  <span><?php echo $r['id'];?></span><span><?php echo $r['name'];?></span>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="<?php echo $no?>">Add</button>
<?php $no++;}?>
```

This php code will display 5 buttons with the different id (1,2,3 and so on). What I want to happen is when I click any of the 5 buttons the jQuery function will show its id.
I have this code.

```
var btn = $('.btn-success').attr('id');
$('#'+btn).click(function(){
  alert(btn);
 }
```

but, it only appears for the first id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('.btn-success')` gets all the elements, but when you add `attr()`, it only gets the attribute for the first element in the collection.

You can just attach the event handler to the entire collection, and use `this.id` to get the ID of the clicked element inside the event handler

```
$('.btn-success').on('click', function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
$('.btn-success').click(function(){
    $(this).attr('id');
    alert(btn);
}
```

I would suggest not to use numbers as ID value, if possible. Check this link [Valid ID and Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html?lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
$('.btn-success').on('click', function(){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

In you view:

```
<?php $no=1; foreach($result as $r){?>
   <span><?php echo $r['id'];?></span><span><?php echo $r['name'];?></span>
   <button onclick="abc(this.id)" class="btn btn-success" id="<?php echo $no?>">Add</button>
<?php $no++;}?>
```

Use this javascript function as :

```
function abc(id){
     alert(id);
}
```